# Possible to create objects and push them to a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote some C# code back in time, and now I'm trying to do the same in Javascript, but I'm confused about creating two dimensional arrays and if it's possible to both create and push new object into an 2D array?

How I did in C#:

```
gameGrid[column][row] = new ColorObject(x,y,color);
```

And then get values from methods like this:

```
gameGrid[1][2].showColor;
```

Would it be possible to add object with push in Javascript like this or are there any other options?

```
gameGrid[col][row].push(new ColorObject(x,y,color));
```

Comment: Maybe `gameGrid[col].push(new ColorObject(x, y, color));` ?

Comment: Judging by your code, yes. That should work. But then, you never mentioned *how you made `gameGrid`* nor any error in the console. Still practicing on reading the crystal ball.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer It's simple to create a 2D array in C#, but not in Javascript. I was thinking about a jagged array, like an array in an array. Would that really work?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Creating a `m`x`n` array in JS is simple: `Array(m).fill().map(a => Array(n))`

Comment: Push will add a value at the end of an array. `gameGrid[col][row]` must then be an array of values. If you want to do exactly the same as in C#, assign a single object instance, you do it the same as in C#  `gameGrid[column][row] = new ColorObject(x,y,color);`.

Comment: Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you probably did something like:

```
ColorObject[][] gameGrid = new ColorObject[10][];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  gameGrid[i] = new ColorObject[10];
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    gameGrid[i][j] = new ColorObject(i, j, someValue);
  }
}
```

Well, that's practically identical with JavaScript:

```
var gameGrid = new Array(10); // or "= [];" and then push instead of "gameGrid[i] = ..."
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  gameGrid[i] = new Array(10); // or "[]" and then push instead of "gameGrid[i][j] = ..."
  for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    gameGrid[i][j] = new ColorObject(i, j, someValue);
  }
}
```

After that, you have a 10 by 10 2d array that you can access just like you did in C#:

```
gameGrid[row][col] = new ColorObject(x, y, color);
gameGrid[1][2].showColor();
```

Comment: In C# I used two loops. One for the rows and one for the columns.

Comment: You could do it in JS as well... I just showed a shortcut to generate an empty array. If you want to initialize with instances, add an inner loop and push values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you have time to also add an alternative with an inner loop? I'm not sure how that would look in JS.

Comment: Thanks, but why did you removed the shortcut!? I like to learn some new and would like to compare the both way to create a 2D array. Can you just add that code again?

Comment: I did it because that's what you asked for, but see the comments - I still explain how this can be done with the `[]` array object and `push()`. (P.S. you can see older answer versions if you click on the "edited .." link)

Comment: I wrote "to also add..." hoping that the first alternative would be left. But it's OK. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @3D-kreativ Yeah I see it now. Sorry I didn't understand the first time. Do you really need me to edit the answer again, or were you able to see the alternatives?

Comment: No, I clicked on the "edited" link and took a copy of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your gameGrid is an Array of Array, then you would just:

```
gameGrid[c][r] = new ColorObject(x,y,color);
```

```
var gameGrid = [];
var cols = 10;
var rows = 10;
for (var c=0; c<cols; c++) {
    gameGrid.push([]);
    for (var r=0; r<rows; r++) {
        gameGrid[c][r] = new ColorObject(x,y,color);
    }
}
```

`push` in javascript is a method of the Array object, if you want to use that, it becomes:

```
for (var c=0; c<cols; c++) {
    gameGrid.push([]);
    for (var r=0; r<rows; r++) {
        gameGrid[c].push(new ColorObject(x,y,color));
    }
}
```